# No paste: action in canPerformAction:withSender:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, paste, uiresponder

I am trying to forcibly hide the Paste bubble on my `UITextField`.
My implementation is to specify a list of prohibited selectors from `UIResponderStandardEditActions`, store it in an AssociatedValue in a `UIResponder` category and quit category's `canPerformAction:withSender:` prematurely if action is found in the list. This is quite tempting approach, because it lets to control any Responder in the project.

Problem is no `paste:` action reaches any `canPerformAction:withSender:` method for the whole responder chain when I tap inside my `UITextField`. I wrote a category on `UIResponder` and swizzled `canPerformAction:withSender:` there, so I can be sure:

```
- (BOOL)my_canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    NSString *string = NSStringFromSelector(action);
    BOOL prohibited = [self.prohibitedActions containsObject:string];

    if (prohibited) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL canPerform = [self my_canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    return canPerform;
}
```

The whole catch for my hierarchy is:

```
 cut:
 copy:
 select:
 selectAll:
 delete:
 _promptForReplace:
 _transliterateChinese:
 _insertDrawing:
 _showTextStyleOptions:
 _lookup:
 _define:
 _define:
 _addShortcut:
 _accessibilitySpeak:
 _accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
 _accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
 _share:
 makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

Prohibiting `_promptForReplace:` does not help. Also, my TextField does not implement `canPerformAction:withSender:`.

So, what should I do to track down and hide that nasty paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating category on `UITextField` instead of `UIResponder` did the trick.
Subclassing `UITextField` and implementing `canPerformAction:withSender:` works either.

It turned out that category on UIResponder does not affect `canPerformAction:withSender:` on `UITextField`, even though `UITextField` IS-A `UIResponder`. I do not know whether it is a bug in iOS or some oddity in it's internal behavior.

My fault was to rely too much on swizzling. I do not recommend you this "universal" approach like making a category with a list of "prohibited" action selectors to work with any responder.

Answer (score 1):

So in swift I will do like this:

```
UIMenuController.shared.menuItems?.removeAll(where: {$0.title == "paste"})
```

In objective-c you can try something like this:

```
 UIMenuController * controller = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
     NSArray * items = [controller menuItems]; // These are all custom items you added
     NSMutableArray * finalItemsYouWant = [NSMutableArray array];
     // Here you can check what items you don't want and then remove it
     [controller setMenuItems:finalItemsYouWant];
```

So try finding out all the menu items and forcefully remove the one you want

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but your example covers only custom menu items, whereas my question regards system actions, like Paste, Copy, Cut, Select, Select All etc.